# Submit form and send email with attachment

Tags: component

I need an extension recommendation for the following scenario:

- Page with a form, where the user can input their email address and select a file
- File file selected needs to be delivered via email as an attachment (PDF file).

I have tried jforms and breezingforms but without the desired outcome.

Comment: Does everything you require - http://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-form.html

Comment: There is a free extension [JxiForms][1] which will do all these task. [1]:http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/23152

Comment: the best solution for me is Fabrik
http://fabrikar.com

Comment: Do you mean select a file in a select list and that file is sent in the email? If so that could be more then some of the form components where built for, though I have not tried them all.

Comment: @PatiiHenrii please progress your abandoned question.  Did you use Johan's answer with satisfaction? If so, please accept the answer.  If you used something else please post a new answer to describe what you used, what you learned in the process, and why it is a wise choice.

Answer (score 1):

I do this regularly with BreezingForms (1.8.x), what kind of problem did you run into?

Try this:

- Create a File upload field
- Switch to the "Advanced" tab
- Select "Attach to admin mail(s)"

If the user uploads a file, it will be stored on your server AND added to the admin email.

[image: Attach to admin mail(s)]